# Linux Development C/C++/bash/python on windows-7

Tags: cygwin, mingw, development-environment, virtualbox, interix

Before resorting to stackoverflow, i have spend a lot of times looking for the solutions. I have been a linux-user/developer for few years, now shifting to windows-7.
I am looking for seting-up a development environment (mainly c/c++/bash/python) on my windows machine. Solutions i tired -

- VirtuaBox latest, with grml-medium (very light debian-based distro)
  some how managed to install it in VBox, but lots of issues still regarding Guest-Additions, sharing files, screen-resolutions. Tired with it, now.
- MinGW
  installed it, added to %PATH%, along with GVIM. Now i can use powershell, run gvim, vim, and mingw from the shell as bash. But no manpages, its a lot of convenience to have them availble, locally and offline. But i think it gives me a gcc development 
  Do i need mySys now. i can installed it if it provides me with manpages and ssh.
- Cygwin
  Has avoided till now. But i think it will give me manpages, gcc-utils, python-latest.
- Something called Interix.
  any taker for that. is it recommened.

What are the best practices? What are you guys following, i dont have a linux-box to ssh to, well if Vbox things works fine at some point of it, i can then ssh to my VBox. I have lost of time setting it up, so abandoning it for a while.
I think only VirtualBox solution will let try things like IPtables, or other linux-system-frameworks.

I checked this
[Best setup for Linux development from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964850/best-setup-for-linux-development-from-windows)
do you recommend coLinux or its derivatives. If yes advices or consideration before i try that.

Comment: FYI, latest python version in Cygwin is 2.5.2.

Comment: You can still install Python 3.0 in cygwin. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440547/installing-python-3-0-on-cygwin

Comment: I think the way i have installed minGW and then added to %path, i think i can do the same for python too. Install its windows exe, and add it to the %path, and good to go.

Comment: Any one recommending colinux. It looks like a recent solution, I think ie why it is not so popular, but has anyone given it a try.

Comment: Okay, why are you doing this?  If you're writing apps to run on Windows, why not go the whole hog and use Visual Studio?  If you're still targetting Linux, why use Windows?  In any case, if you want to make sure something runs on Linux, you should test it on Linux.  This means that the only good answer is running Linux in some form, like VirtualBox or just dual-booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend VirtualBox+Ubuntu. Cygwin just doesn't cut it for certain tasks and is in beta for Win7.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do for Python development on Windows:

- EasyEclipse for Python (includes eclipse, subclipse, pydev)
- GNU Win32 [Native Windows ports for GNU tools](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)
- Vim and Emacs (for non-IDE editing work)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Bloodshed DevC++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) as a good basic non-microsoft specific Windows solution for developing ANSI C/C++ code. Personally I just use Visual Studio 2008 and ignore all the Microsoft specific extensions.

For Python there is the wonderful Komodo Edit software that is free, personally the IDE version is what I prefer, but I use an old 3.5.3 version that works for me. And they have a very popular Python package called ActivePython as well, that has a bunch of Windows specific extension modules.

Personally cygwin just feels and acts like a hack to me and is painful to setup and maintain. I think running Linux/Unix in a Virtual Machine is much less hassle if you are looking for a *nix environment. Getting a really genuine *nix environment feel is going to be very hard under Windows.

Comment: regarding cygwin is true, it will more troublesome to maintain than Vbox-linux solution. I have no idea, does cygwin users share the same view.

Comment: Cygwin has improved over the years in its pacakging, and its pretty good at the moment. is it by no means a hack it might add a level of indirection for some aspects in its re-implementation of POSIX. The setup is pretty much point and click. Cygwin also allows "write once-ish and (maybe almost) run everytwhere (sometimes)".

Answer (score 0):

I would see if MSysGit can provide what you want first. also since man pages aren't really anything hugely impressive... it might just be possible to just copy them. I've had problems with cygwin, although to be honest I'm not happy with MSys, MSysGit, or Cygwin. I wish someone would build one that was more... linux like. I would if I had to use windows every day, fortunately I only have to use windows sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

IMO I'd say VirtualBox + Gentoo Linux + KDevelop4, Gentoo will give you the control you need over your environment.
I'm doing exactly the opposite of you, I have gcc/qt4 installed on wine to compile for windows and using Linux primarily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do development of POSIX applications (mostly command line), with all the familiar Linux tools, then cygwin is your best bet.
It probably include everything you are used to.

But if you will try to do Windows development (anything with UI, drivers, services), then Visual Studio is really gold.

And in general Visual Studio is just great for anything, if you want to spend the time and money. Good IDE, great debugger. I highly recommend it. And if you are in Rome, do what the Romans do :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestions hold if you are not going to do complex template programming as the c++ IDE's other than visual studio SUCK, they cannot efficiently index modern C++ code (the boost library).

I would suggest using Netbeans (it has far better support for C++ than eclipse/CDT) with the following two build environments. Both are important if you want to cross-compile and test against POSIX and win32. This is not a silver-bullet, you should test on different variants of UNIX once in a while:

I would suggest installing Mingw and Msys for windows development, its nice when you can use awk, grep, sed etc on your code :D generative programming is easier with shell tools as well -- writing generative build scripts is a bitch to do effectively of the command line in windows (powershell might have changed this).

I would ALSO suggest installing Cygwin and using that on the side. Mingw is for programming against the win32 low-level API, Cygwin is for programming against the POSIX standard. Cygwin also compiles a lot of software that you would otherwise have to port.

Also once you get your project up and running you can use CMAKE as build environment, its the best thing since sliced bread :P You can get it to spit out build definition for anything and everything -- including visual studio.