# Python 3.x in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cygwin

I have the `python` package in Cygwin on Windows 7. However, typing

```
python -V
```

returns

```
Python 2.6.8
```

This is a pretty low version of Python... I could use Python 3.x (whatever version is newest, preferably). I've seen some people say you have to download a `.zip` or `.tar` manually to get it (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440547/installing-python-3-0-on-cygwin?rq=1) question). My questions are as follows (please note this is NOT a duplicate of the linked question):

- Can I get Python 3.x somehow using the Cygwin package manager?
- Can/should I get rid of Python 2.6 if I manage to get Python 3.x running? None of my code runs on anything specific to Python 2.6.

Thanks

Comment: Python 3 does not seem to be in the cygwin repo (http://cygwin.com/packages/) - so you probably have to install it from source. Under most linux flavours python3 will use a different name than python2 (most often python3) so it should not produce any problems for you if you keep python2 installed, if cygwin behaves this way as well.

Comment: "Python 2.6.8 was released on April 10, 2012." Pretty old? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have noted, the version of Python 2.6 that's installed with Cygwin is recent; Python release numbers are not linear with respect to time. The [Python releases page](https://www.python.org/downloads/) details which versions were released on which date.

You can install Python3 if you want, using Cygwin Ports. This is a collection of Cygwin packages that are not ready for general release on the main Cygwin mirrors, but have been compiled ready to be used on Cygwin. I've written [some instructions over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/438413/python3-on-cygwin/438687#438687) which describe in more detail how to do this.

(I'd avoid installing from source, as [Lennart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126214/lennart-regebro) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11190915/220155), as I'd expect this will require non-trivial fixes to make it work on Cygwin.)

As noted in the above-linked SuperUser question, there's no need to uninstall Python 2.6 to install Python 3; the two run happily side-by-side.

That said, beware your claim that "None of my code runs on anything specific to Python 2.6": Python 3.x is *not* back compatible with Python 2.x, and code written for Python 2.x will generally not work on Python 3.x without work to adapt it. The [Python 3.0.1 What's New Guide](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) has a good overview of the changes in Python 3.x.

**Update**: As of Wed 25 July 2012, [Python 3.2.3 is included in the standard Cygwin installer](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-07/msg00553.html). Just run Cygwin's `setup.exe` again (download it from [cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com) again if you need to), and you should be able to select and install it like any other package.