# Running python 3.2 programs from cygwin(windows 7 user)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I need to be able to run python 3.2 scripts from cygwin.However,the current setup of cygwin shows it isnt compatible with that.I searched on the internet and saw in some other forums that people have ben unable to do it.Anyone here has any idea how  to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can [install Python 3.1.5 using Cygwin Ports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191436/220155).

Python 3.2 hasn't been ported to Cygwin, almost certainly because it's relatively unstable compared to 3.1, which is now only taking security fixes. If you want Python 3.2, you'll need to port it to Cygwin yourself.

Comment: Are you just guessing by *relatively unstable* claim? If so, that's wrong. `3.1` is not getting any bug fixes at all in fact, and one should use it only if they don't have a choice.

Comment: @Tshepang: Stable means few changes; not taking bug fixes *is* stable. If you want stability, having a product with some known bugs is better than a product that has had those bugs recently fixed, where there has been less field testing and thus more risk of hitting an unknown bug (and potentially a more serious bug, such as one that introduces a security vulnerability).

Comment: Your definition of *stable* is unusual, but I do get your point.

Answer (score 1):

As of yesterday (Wed 25 July 2012), [Python 3.2.3 is included in the standard Cygwin installer](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-07/msg00553.html). Just run Cygwin's `setup.exe` again (download it from [cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com) again if you need to), and you should be able to select and install it like any other package.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.one solution i have found is that i can invoke cygwin through command window and then pass instructions using subprocess.However being able to run python 3.2 codes from cygwin would have been more preferable to me rather than the other way round!!